# Smoothness is the same as regularity at closed points for a finite type scheme of pure dimension $d$ over an algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is exercise 12.2.I in Vakil's notes:

> Suppose $X$ is a finite type scheme of pure dimension $d$ over an
>   algebraically closed field $k$. Show that $X$ is regular at its closed points if and
>   only if it is smooth.

For the forward direction, for a closed point $p$, $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=d$. From Exercise 12.1.G, one has that the Zasiki cotangent space at a closed point is given by the cokernel of the Jacobian matrix. If $X$ is regular at closed points, then corank of the Jacobian matrix is $d$ at all closed points, hence by Exercise 12.2.H, the Jacobian matrix has corank $d$ at all points. This shows the smoothness. Conversely, smoothness of $X$ implies the Jacobian has corank $d$ at all points, in particular closed points.

Is the result true for $k$ not algebraically closed? I don't see why it's required that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: The essential issue here is that smooth is equivalent to geometrically regular for a scheme (locally) of finite type over a field ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/038X)), and the Jacobian criterion sees _regularity_, not geometric regularity, as the linked examples show. As geometric regularity is just regularity over an algebraically closed field, this explains why restricting to the case of an algebraically closed field makes these concepts coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need that this is true after changing the base to the algebraic closure (or equivalently for the separable closure or all extensions). What I am saying is that one way of defining smooth is as geometrically regular, but regular is in general not the same. So here we assume that $k$ is algebraically closed to get rid of this "geometrically" and then we have that smoothness and regular coincides (which is the result that you are talking about). For a concrete counterexample that these notions don't need to coincide, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236388/is-it-true-that-a-variety-is-smooth-if-all-of-its-local-rings-are-regular-local.).

Comment: Vakil defines a $k$-scheme to be smooth of dimension $d$ if it is of pure dimension $d$ and with an affine open cover $\operatorname{Spec}k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_r)$ where the Jacobian matrix has corank $d$ at all points. With this definition, I don't know why the exercise in Vakil requires $k$ to be algebraically closed. Does the Jacobian criterion require $k$ to be algebraically closed?

Comment: I did not get a notification that you answered, sorry. But as you can see, Kreiser found another post that treats your question.